# How to deploy Pinax without root Access to Apache?

Tags: apache, pinax

I tried Pinax, and it works great on my local machine, but how do I deploy it to my webhost server? I will not have root access to the server, and can not change APACHE server's config.
I can only edit .htaccess file, will that be enough for Pinax deployment?
ChengLong

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

http://pinaxproject.com/docs/dev/deployment/

In short:

- Create a local_settings.py alongside settings.py for your host-specific settings (like database connection, e-mail, etc).
- Configure mod_wsgi.
- Set up cron job for mailer and asynchronous notifications.

OR

You could check out http://gondor.io and stop worry about all this server configuration stuff.